# retrieving one field from datatable C#, not working

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm making a project where you see a list of movies in a listbox and there's a button with view movie description using listbox.value.

Below is my function to retrieve the description from a database.
But i'm getting the following error:

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Entertainment.FilmsDetails.filmId'   H:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Entertainment\Entertainment\FilmsDetails.cs  43  39  Entertainment

```
 public static string DetailMovie(int movieId)
    {
        string command;
        command = "SELECT description" +
            "FROM MovieDescription" +
            " WHERE movieId=  " + movieId;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, connectionString);
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(datatable);

        object o = datatable.Rows[0]["description"];
    }
```

Comment: there is no problem with the above code, where are you accessing feild `'Entertainment.FilmsDetails.filmId`? please share that code.

Comment: post or specify which is the line where the error occurs.

Comment: make `filmId` field static

Comment: this is a dutch code translated to English so filmId relates to movieId.

the error is in the line `where movieid=  " + movieid; `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sql command you are passing to your db looks like the following:

```
SELECT descriptionFROM MovieDescription WHERE movieID= 1
```

Make sure to add a space between description and FROM

Start with that.

**UPDATE**

My best guess without seeing more code is that you are trying to access a property or member variable that is not static within your static method. The only variable that you aren't creating within the method itself is the connectionString, which if it isn't marked as static, would throw this compiler error.

```
// connectionString is possibly not static
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, connectionString);
```

Does your function need to be static, or can you make the connectionString static?

**UPDATE 2**

You also will need to return a value out of your function.

Comment: @ohiodoug so what if I change it to `public void DetailMovie (int MovieId)`. 
and add `return`. in the end. Can I then use the DetailMovie to make it appaer in a messagebox?

Comment: You would be able to use the value returned by DetailMovie in a messagebox. Just don't abuse it because you are making a roundtrip call to the db each time you call this function, and as with any db call, you can hurt performance if you aren't conservative with its use.

Comment: @ohiodoug okay but if I want to return the void in a messagebox I get a `cannot convert from void to string and best overloaded method match for messagebox.show has some invalid arguments`

Comment: DetailMovie is supposed to return a string, so make sure it does. It sounds like what you're trying to do with the message box is a different question.